# Issue with Jmeter Regular Expression Extractor

Tags: jmeter

I'm attempting to pull the text following,

```
 <script id="startupVarsScript">
        startupVars = {
            startup:
```

Using the regular expression extractor but im not having any joy.

Iv tried the following regular regular expressions

> ```
>   <script id="startupVarsScript">
>             startupVars = {
>                 startup:
> ```

```
 startupVars = {
            startup:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add white space catcher `(\s+)` between text, full [regex test](https://regex101.com/r/imL3L5/1):

```
<script id="startupVarsScript">(\s+)startupVars(\s+)=(\s+){(\s+)startup
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for the answer - this worked a treat.

Comment: You can accept it by clicking on V sign to the left of the answer